# How to apply morphological operations like clearing border and removing small objects on color images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I have a color image:

[image]

Then I applied k-means algorithm and selected this image as the suitable cluster:

[image: selected image]

I want to apply morphological operations like cleaning border, filling holes and remove small objects using MATLAB but these operations work only on gray-scaled or binary images in MATLAB.

I want to select just the cell in the midst of the image and extract the contour as the final step.

The code is :

```
NbIm = size(names1,1);
n1 = 1;
n2 = NbIm;
for  n = n1:n2
    %  1- Lecture de l'image originale
    ImPath1 = strcat(DirName1,ImName1(n)); % Chemin de chaque image
    Im_originale = imread(char(ImPath1));  % Chargement image

    %  1-  Appliquer la méthode K-means pour générer TROIS classes
    cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
    lab_he = applycform(Im_originale,cform);
    ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
    nrows = size(ab,1);
    ncols = size(ab,2);
    ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);
    nColors = 3;

    % repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
    [cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
        'Replicates',3);
    pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
    % imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');

    segmented_images = cell(1,3);
    rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);
    for k = 1:nColors
        color = Im_traiter;
        color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
        segmented_images{k} = color;
    end
    C1=segmented_images{1};
    C2=segmented_images{2};
    C3=segmented_images{3};

    % 2-  Selectionner la classe à traiter
    [m ind]=min(cluster_center);
    ClusterChoix=ind;
    Im1_traiter=segmented_images{ClusterChoix};
end
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?”/"Any suggestions" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You already state that the operations only work on grey scale images; did you try simply converting your image to grey scale?

Comment: Convert to grayscale, apply the operations, then use the mask and apply it over all channels.

Comment: Please post your code for how you obtained this color image from k-means clustering. I think you transfered colors there also, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Cris Luengo , I edited my question and I posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your image is actually binary as you care about the shape and operations on shape.

Binarize and apply the binary operations, then merge with the original (transfer the colors to the binarized pixels). You may have to extrapolate data at new pixels that appear. There are so-called inpainting techniques available. You might investigate poisson reconstruction, which is similar to a weighted average of the neighboring known pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code as follows to apply some morphological processing:

Original code:

```
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);
for k = 1:nColors
   color = Im_traiter;
   color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
   segmented_images{k} = color; 
end
```

Modified code:

```
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
segmented_images = cell(1,3);
for k = 1:nColors
   mask = pixel_labels == k;
   % Insert morphological operations here on the binary image `mask`
   color = Im_traiter;
   color(repmat(~mask,[1 1 3])) = 0;
   segmented_images{k} = color; 
end
```

Comment: Hello @Cris Luengo, I modified the code as you mentioned but I get this error  :

Undefined function or variable 'rgb_label'.

Error in Initilialisation_K_means_Couleur (line 139)
         mask = rgb_label == k;

Comment: @MarwaBraiki: Sorry, typo. I fixed the post. It should have been `pixel_labels`, not `rgb_label`.